# CFor in Haxe using Macros

Tags: for-loop, macros, haxe

So, I love macros (yell at me).

I was trying to create a macro in Haxe, which allows me to write the traditional (C++, Java) for-loop and have the same functionality. But I am quite a beginner in Haxe...

**Code:**

```
import haxe.macro.Expr;

class Cfor {

    macro public static function cfor(init: Expr, cond: Expr, post: Expr, body: Expr) {
        return macro {
            $init;

            while ($cond) {
                $body;
                $post;
            }
        }
    }

    public static function main() {
            trace("Traced");
            cfor(var i = 0, i < 100, i++, {
                    var x = i * 2;
                    trace(x);
            });     
    }

}
```

**Questions**:

- It already works (that specific test), but it's not that close to the traditional for-loop. **How to improve that?**
- Do you have any other improvements (style/functionality) for this code?
- Is there anything target specific which I should know of about this code?
- How can I see what this call to cfor expands to?

Comment: You can do `import CFor.cfor` in other classes, and then just run `cfor(cond)` without having to call `CFor.cfor()`, which helps a little.  @Franco's answer below show's a way to make it look even more like a classic C look

Comment: To view generated code, use `haxe -D dump=pretty mybuild.hxml`.  It will create a "dump/" folder, with "CFor.dump", which shows you the generated code.

Comment: That dumping is neat, thanks. What I did before was to compile to Java and look at the output, but obviously that's not a good option.

Comment: Until yesterday I did the same thing, I only found out about the "-D dump=pretty" option a few hours before I saw your question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this?

https://gist.github.com/dpeek/7476625

The approach is different (applied to the context) but I think it is a little closer to the desired outcome.

I don't see any potential target specific issues with your code.

Comment: That's a very interesting thing as well, though I wanted to stay clear of build macros... From what I understood, this code loops all expressions which probably takes longer than a standard macro.